# "Sign with a click" with Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, digital-signature

I'm currently using Docusign on a website using embedded signing in a iFrame with success since 2016.

For a new use case, we would like to use Docusign again, but we would like to customize the signature experience to make it simpler; we would like to have a "Click with a check" interface where the clients could sign the envelope with the unique check of a checkbox.

I met some difficulties to see if this change on Docusign interface is possible? I'm looking into Docusign Rest API & Resource files doc to do something like that, but I don't see any clue to tell me the way to go.
We would like the following signature experience: -Clients are asked to click on a link to go to signature enveloppe -Once on the envelope, they are asked to check a checkbox to sign the document, and to enter a code sent by sms to finish the signature process.

We want to simplify as must as possible the signature process for ours suscribers.
We would like the following signature experience: -Clients are asked to click on a link to go to signature enveloppe -Once on the envelope, they are asked to check a checkbox to sign the document, and to enter a code sent by sms to finish the signature process.

Does someone have an idea for that? is it possible to get that type of signature experience with Docusign?

Answer (score 0):

Signatures within DocuSign are collected via the Signature tab. At this time check box tabs cannot be customized to offer a unique signing experience, and can only be set to optional (not required).

Could you be more specific as to what type of signing experience you were looking to provide for your clients?

Answer (score 0):

At this time the check box tabs are limited to optional-only, they cannot be set to required. While DocuSign does offer a system for [validating via SMS message](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-recipient-authentication) , this validation takes place prior to the end-user accessing their envelope.

It is possible to use a validation / regex pattern to require that a specific string be entered into a text box, but this would have to be set up beforehand.

Comment: StackOverflow is NOT a back-and-forth forum system. Next time, please EDIT your first answer to update it with more information as needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DocuSign Click product](https://www.docusign.com/products/click). It provides a simplified user interface for the signer.